# Javascript - how to remove .com or .net or .org from location.href

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, dns

I need to remove .com or any domain type from location.href
for example:

```
sub.domain.com
```

and I need to return

```
sub.domain
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way: (no RegeEx needed)

```js
var url = "sub.domain.com"
url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("."))

document.write(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
var str = 'sub.domain.com';
var end = str.lastIndexOf('.');
return str.substring(0, end);
```

A full function would look as simple as following:

```
function stripTopLevelDomain(var domain) {
  return domain.substring(0, domain.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simple Regex solution :

```
"sub.domain.com".replace(/([.]\w+)$/, '')
```

---

```
[.] : the literal character .
\w+ : match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
$   : assert position at end of the string
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
alert("sub.domain.com".replace(/([.]\w+)$/, ''));
```

Hope this helps.